# Using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema is there a way to intercept the generation of the "definitions" name?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

Given I have the following type:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyGenericClass<bool> Gen { get; set; }
}

public class MyGenericClass<T>
{
    [Required]
    public T Prop { get; set; }
}
```

and I set up the schema generator like so

```
var generator = new JSchemaGenerator
{
     ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
     SchemaIdGenerationHandling = SchemaIdGenerationHandling.None
};

generator.GenerationProviders.Add(
     new StringEnumGenerationProvider { CamelCaseText = true });
```

I get the following schema

```json
{
  "definitions": {
    "MyGenericClass<Boolean>": {
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "prop": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "prop"
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "gen": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/MyGenericClass<Boolean>"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "gen"
  ]
}
```

Which is great except that the service I need to share the schema with does not like the angle brackets '<>'.

Is there a way to intercept the creation of the definition name so I can strip out the <>? Note none of the other **SchemaIdGenerationHandling** work either.

Annoyingly something like

```
public class GenericSchemaProvider : JSchemaGenerationProvider
{
    public override bool CanGenerateSchema(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context)
    {

        return context.ObjectType.IsGenericType && !context.ObjectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable));
    }

    public override JSchema GetSchema(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context)
    {
        return CanGenerateSchema(context) ? CreateSchemaWithCustomId(context, context.Required) : null;
    }

    private static JSchema CreateSchemaWithCustomId(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context, Required required)
    {
        var schema = context.Generator.Generate(context.ObjectType, required != Required.Always);
        schema.Id = new Uri(TypeName(context.ObjectType), UriKind.Relative);
        return schema;
    }

    private static string TypeName(Type type, string acc = "")
    {
        var name = type.Name;
        var index = name.IndexOf('`');
        return index == -1 ? acc+name : TypeName(type.GetGenericArguments()[0],acc+name.Substring(0, index));
    }
}
```

almost works

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "MyGenericClassNullableDouble": {
      "$id": "MyGenericClassNullableDouble",
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "prop": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "prop"
      ]
    },
    "MyGenericClassDouble": {
      "$id": "MyGenericClassDouble",
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "prop": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "prop"
      ]
    },
    "MyGenericClassBoolean": {
      "$id": "MyGenericClassBoolean",
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "prop": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "prop"
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "genBool": {
      "$ref": "MyGenericClassBoolean"
    },
    "genDouble": {
      "$ref": "MyGenericClassDouble"
    },
    "genNulableDouble": {
      "$ref": "MyGenericClassNullableDouble"
    }
  }
}
```

But the references are not proper references to definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are on the right track, I think you just need to provide your own implementation of the `JSchemaGenerationProvider`, instead of using `StringEnumGenerationProvider`.  Something like [creating a custom provider](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/CreateCustomProvider.htm):

```
public class FormatSchemaProvider : JSchemaGenerationProvider
{
    public override JSchema GetSchema(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context)
    {
        // customize the generated schema for these types to have a format
        if (context.ObjectType == typeof(MyGenericClass<bool>))
        {
            return CreateSchemaWithFormat(
               context.ObjectType, context.Required, "MyGenericClass");
        }
        // use default schema generation for all other types
        return null;
    }

    private JSchema CreateSchemaWithFormat(Type type, Required required, string format)
    {
        JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
        JSchema schema = generator.Generate(type, required != Required.Always);
        schema.Format = format;
        return schema;
    }
}
```

Then add the new generation provider:

```
JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
generator.GenerationProviders.Add(new FormatSchemaProvider());
JSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(MyClass));
```

Comment: This does not change the definitions entry. It just adds a "format"
"definitions": {
    "MyGenericClass<Boolean>": {
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "Prop": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "Prop"
      ],
      "format": "MyGenericClass"
    }
  }

Comment: I need to make "definitions": {    "MyGenericClass<Boolean>" become "definitions": {    "MyGenericClassBoolean" and all properties refer to the same name i.e. "properties": {
    "gen": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/MyGenericClass<Boolean>"
    } should become "properties": {
    "gen": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/MyGenericClassBoolean"
    }

Comment: @Yoztastic - You will probably need a [`CustomConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)